# DrawerLayout : Drawer hand? Drawer indicator?

Tags: android

I don't know how to really call this but I want to make menu drawer like in drawerlayout but when drawer is close there will be like drawer indicator a;ways float on the left side of screen like this

open

[image]

close

[image]

is there any way to do like this?

Comment: I understand how to use `slidingmenu` and `navigationdrawer` but i just have problem of put indicator when it's close

Comment: Indicator you can put it on your own in the layout only. Once you understand the demo. Check out in my answer.

Comment: if i put on my layout only so how can i make it move with drawer or i need to have some listener to control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found library https://github.com/NikolaDespotoski/DrawerLayoutEdgeToggle works well as i wish for.

Answer (score 0):

For this you should be using the [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html). Here are some examples:

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html
http://www.recursiverobot.com/post/59642335041/trying-slidingpanelayout-with-fragments-in-android

Because you are working with `Fragments` here you could tweak the layout so to keep the indicator in the layout.

Comment: thank you for your answer but how can i tweak layout as you said any example?

Comment: @zilchrhythm Using relativelayout i guess you could use the alignParentRight and the centerVertical and place a button there.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) + ActionbarSherlock is a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Go for [Sliding Menu using Drawer](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/) which best suites your functionality.

Also you can check the guide for [Navigation Drawer in Android](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)